# Can i force iframe to show certain part of page using css or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show video from one of the website since i cant consume it i though of using iframe and some how show only video part of the iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.dmi.ae/live.asp?lang=en&ChannelID=2" width="650" height="476" >
</iframe>
```

Example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjatJ/1/)

I am not sure how i can using jQuery to show only DIV wrapper which has video embedded

`<div class="floatFirst omega_t3">` or just by `css` if we can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution works suites my requirement as compared to one provided `ConnorRoberts` as in his solution social media plugin floats which is not what i want when i wrap iframe with `div` as shown in example it hides everything [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VjatJ/4/)

```
#my-div
{
    width    : 650px;
    height   : 500px;
    overflow : hidden;
    position : relative;
}

#my-iframe
{
    position : absolute;
    top      : -320px;
    left     : -150px;
    width    : 1280px;
    height   : 1200px;
}

<div id="my-div">
<iframe id="my-iframe"  src="http://www.dmi.ae/live.asp?lang=en&ChannelID=2" width="650" height="476" scrolling="no"  >
</iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it on the condition that the page (coming from another domain) you show is sent with [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) allowing your origin (or any origin).

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            $content = $(httpRequest.responseText);
            $(iframeId).html($content.find('.floatFirst.omega_t3'));
        }
    }
}
httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.dmi.ae/live.asp?lang=en&ChannelID=2');
httpRequest.send();
```

For more information about how to set CORS headers, see http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I appreciate your response it is not working i am doing something wrong http://jsfiddle.net/VjatJ/2/

Comment: I had a look at the site : unsurprisingly it doesn't set CORS headers. If you can't get them to set the headers, you can't change what is displayed unless you have a direct URL to the content you want.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe there is a vulnerability somewhere allowing direct access but I don't know it and using it would certainly not be allowed by their conditions of service. If a site is willing to have its content displayed in part, it usually makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not an ideal solution...

I had a play and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/XrdRH/ it still needs a little refinement with getting the distances right and all but all that's required to change it is changing the offsets.

```
top:-303px; left: 10px;
```

The entire code used is (required to submit):

```
<iframe src="http://www.dmi.ae/live.asp?lang=en&ChannelID=2" width="680" height="855" style="position:absolute; top:-303px; left: 10px; overflow: hidden;">
```

You should look to find a nicer solution, but this does just about work :)

Comment: I did the same by wrapping iframe inside div tag, solution under comments `@dystroy solution` Since it working i will mark you answer as correct